ESTA and dual Canadian/ EU citizenship
I am a Canadian living in the UK (with permanent residence as a EU citizen).
I'm about to leave Canada to return to the UK, where I live. I will be transiting via Newark, which I have not done in a long time.
My plan is to check in at the airport in Canada with my Canadian passport to avoid the ESTA, showing my EU passport too should any questions be asked regarding my right to stay in the UK.
At CBP in the US, I would also do as above, until I reach the UK where I will use my EU passport to enter the UK.
I am travelling with my children who are are holders of dual Canadian/British passports.
Does this sound straightforward? I'm worried the CBP expects me to travel on my EU passport as it is the passport I will use to re-enter the UK, and therefore expect the associated ESTA.
Should I apply for our ESTAs for 'peace of mind' (but would prefer avoiding the fees x 3).
I'm aware variations of this question have been asked previously, but none that represents my circumstances.
Thanking you in advance for your replies.

You would be technically ok, but it would simplify your journey, if you just apply for an ESTA. Any airline staff / border agent, unfamiliar with the rules can ruin your day.

A Canadian citizen does not need an ESTA, traveling without one should work. (But not being a dual Canadian-European citizen I have never done it.)

Which airport in Canada are you departing from, on which airline? You are more than likely to go through pre-clearance (CBP controls) in Canada before you depart rather than in the US. Are both flights on the same booking? If they are not then it's trivial (but there are risks). If they are, ideally the airline should be able to enter different passports for each of the flights (for API) but that's probably asking a bit much. Otherwise the Canadian passport will just do fine. You could even ask the airline to overwrite API info with the EU passports once in EWR, but that's probably overkill.

"I'm worried the CBP expects me to travel on my EU passport as it is the passport I will use to re-enter the UK": there is no such expectation.

We are leaving from YQB Québec city with United Airlines. Both flights are within the same booking.

Further to my previous comment, there's no reason to avoid showing both passports to CBP (but really they're not going to care about which document you're using for your onward travel to the UK).  If you present a Canadian passport and a VWP passport and tell them that you don't have ESTA for the VWP passport, they'll admit you on the Canadian passport.

It's normal for dual nationals to use one country's passport to enter and exit one country, and another country's passport to enter and exit the next country. (For example, see this question.)
So there should be nothing to worry about with entering the US without a visa or ESTA using your Canadian passport, and then entering the UK with your European passport. The only potential issue is whether the airline will let you enter two passports for the second leg from the US to the UK (the Canadian passport for exiting the US, so that it will match the entry, and the European passport for entering the UK). It's not uncommon for airlines dual nationals traveling on multiple passports, so they should have a way of handling it.

They don't need to record the Canadian passport the exiting the US. CBP are (usually) able to match people even when they use different documents for entry and exit. Complications arise when there are discrepancies between the documents (different names, different dates or places of birth...), but in the general case it goes quite smoothly. It's alway worth it to check one's I-94 record afterwards though, to be sure the exit was properly recorded.

leaving from YQB Québec city with United Airlines. Both flights are within the same booking
